# SQL select all using JOIN

Tags: php, sql

I'm using this query to collate two sets of results but I now need to use JOIN instead of UNION to get the second part of the data from another table.

However I need quite a lot of fields and can't seem to find a way to maintain the use of SELECT * when using JOIN.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table.products WHERE category='$cat'  GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY id UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table.products WHERE  type='red' GROUP BY product_id ");
```

Table - products

```
product_id | title    | category | id
0            one         home      10
1            two         home      11
1            two - a     home      12
2            three       work      13
```

Table - product_details

```
product_id | type | size |
0            blue   S
1            blue   M
1            red    L
```

Ultimately I need to list every product in the first table for a given category e.g home,
as there is sometimes two entries or more for a single product id, I need to only select one row for each product id value. I also need to join the second table so I can get the size info, however I must be able to get the size info by preferring a type e.g red.

So for this example I would get a list like:

```
 product_id  | title    | category | type | size
 0             one        home       blue    S
 1             two        home       red     L
```

This excludes product_id 2 as it's not in the home category, the first entry for product_id equaling 1 is selected because of the GROUP BY and ORDER BY and the information on size for product_id 1 is L because it is of type red not blue.

Comment: It isn't really a great idea to use `SELECT *` in production code anyway. It is better to be explicit about the columns needed, _especially_ in join or union queries.  You can do `SELECT t1.*, t2.*`, but common columns (like `id`) will end up overwriting.

Comment: Please post the structures of the tables you are querying, and the kind of output you expect to get. Right now, your use of `GROUP BY` is confusing and inappropriate since you have no aggregate functions (`COUNT(),SUM(),MAX(),MIN(),`etc)

Comment: i'm using group by to prevent duplicates of product_id

Comment: MySQL may give you more or less the result you expect with `GROUP BY`, but it would be a flat-out error in most other RDBMS. Its behavior is somewhat indeterminate when using `GROUP BY` over only a subset of columns from the `SELECT` list.  `SELECT DISTINCT ...` is usually the more appropriate option. In any case, please post some table structures and the output you hope to achieve.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you want a join with an aggregation or aggressive filtering.  Here is an example using `join` and `aggregation`:

```
select p.product_id, p.title, p.category,
       substring_index(group_concat(pd.type order by pd.type = 'red' desc, pd.type), ',', 1) as type,
       substring_index(group_concat(pd.size order by pd.type = 'red' desc, pd.type), ',', 1) as size
from products p join
     product_details pd
     on p.product_id = qpd.product_id
where p.category =  'home'
group by p.product_id;
```

The expression `substring_index(group_concat(. . .))` is choosing one `type` (and one `size`) with precedence given to the `red` type.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be simplified like below since you are using the same table `table.products`. Not sure why you need to `UNION` them.

```
SELECT * FROM table.products 
WHERE category='$cat' 
and type='red'
GROUP BY product_id
```

**EDIT:**

With your edited post, the query should look like

```
select p.product_id,p.title,p.category,q.type,q.size
from products p join product_details q
on p.product_id = q.product_id
where p.category =  'home'
and q.type = 'red'
```

Comment: thanks but what about the select *, also this doesn't eliminate product_id duplicates

Comment: note this is a paired down example there are a lot more fields to retrieve